# Nesting in VueDraggable is not not working

Tags: vue.js, nested, draggable, vuedraggable

here's my problem :

**I'm using the VueDraggable library in order to drag and drop elements between a DragBoard.vue and a DropBoard.vue, and a specific type of element should allow to be nested when it is in the DropBoard.**

I'm going to take this element as an example :

- "Grouped Items"

To do that I've followed this example : https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next/blob/master/example/components/nested-example.vue

**And this is what I get when I drop "Grouped Items" into the DropBoard.vue :**
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDwUf.png)

As you can see, the DropBoard appears a second time inside Grouped items for whatever reason. I've supposed that the nested-draggable tag also loop what is out of the draggable tag and I've no idea how to resolve that...

**dragItems.JSON (used in DragBoard.vue)** :

```js
1st object is a common element
2nd object is a nestable element
[
  {
    "type": "Simple list",
    "title": "Simple list",
    "id": 1,
    "properties": "this is an item property"
  },
  ...
  {
    "type": "Grouped items",
    "title": "Grouped items",
    "id": 10,
    "properties": "this is an item property",
    "tasks": []
  },
 ...
]
```

**DropBoard.vue template:**

```vuejs
<template>
  <div class="board">
    <div class="head">Mock</div>
    <div class="dd-container">
      <draggable
        :list="tasks"
        v-model="dropItems"
        item-key="title"
        :group="{ name: 'items', put: true }"
        @change="log"
      >
        <template #item="{ element }">
          <div
            class="item"
            :key="element"
          >
            <div>
              {{ element.title }}
            </div>
            <nested-draggable
              v-if="element.tasks"
              :tasks="element.tasks"
              class="group-container"
            />
            <div class="trashico" :key="index">
              <i class="fas fa-trash" @click="deleteItem(index)"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </draggable>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**DropBoard.vue script**

```vuejs
<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

export default {
  name: "nested-draggable",

  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  props: {
    dropItems: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    tasks: {
      required: true,
      type: Array,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dropItems: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deleteItem(id) {
      this.dropItems.splice(id, 1);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what I found while using the Vue DevTools, it's quit explicit about the problem.**

See image: [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivt0D.png)

Comment: Can I ask you, what was the problem? I have a problem to create nested lists.

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't figured out how to solve that problem :/ ...

Comment: Did you use another library?

Comment: Nope, I gave up...